# Scheduling wifi

Tags: wireless

I want to start my wifi (enable wifi) let's say 10 minutes later or a specific time. How can I do that on ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: You can set a cron job.

Answer (score 3):

setup cronjob

```
crontab -e
```

edit schedule task here like

```
 a b c d e  nmcli nm wifi on
```

where

```
  a     Minute field          0 to 59
  b     Hour field            0 to 23
  c     Day of Month          1 to 31
  d     Month field           1 to 12
  e     Day Of Week           0 to 6
```